# Conjugate Gradient method (quadratic function)

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods

I am performing conjugate gradient method for finding a minimum with exact directional minimization of matrix(NxN) - vector multiplication ($A*b=x$) refolmulated as quadratic function unconstrained minimization of $f(x) = $$\frac{1}{2}$$ x^T*A*x-b^T*x$
I have done some research and I found a book: [Numerical Optimization](http://www.bioinfo.org.cn/~wangchao/maa/Numerical_Optimization.pdf). There is a conjugate gradient method algorithm explained like this:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzD24.png).
Anyway, I have some doubts about a way of finding α (step-length), beacause in other sources it is done differently. Is this formula correct for quadratic functions?

Answer (score 0):

The Conjugate Gradient algorithm posted in the image is correct and numerically stable.  There are several (I've seen 3) different ways to get $\alpha_k.$  The brute force  "common sense" way that one gets in deriving the CG method is usually not advisable because it is numerically unstable and slow, whereas the other two equivalent ways (one of which you posted) are equally as efficient and stable.  See Golub and Van Loan if you wish to have more of the details.  This book can be found online with a little searching.

Comment: thanks you for your answer. The most important for me is an information whether this formula is appropriate for minimization of quadratic function? Because I'm not sure whether a formula from my image is not a linear approach. This is a part of my university project and that fact is crucial. All I have said in my lectures notes is that: α - found by the directional minimization of $F(x^k+αd^k)$

Comment: The problems of minimizing $f(x)$ and solving $Ax = b$ are equivalent.  The minimum value of $f(x)$ is $-b^TA^{-1}b/2,$ which is achieved by setting $x = A^{-1}b.$  So the formula in the book is the method minimize $f(x)$ correctly, and the solution you get upon convergence will be $x = A^{-1}b.$ This is at least true when $A$ is positive symmetric definite, a common assumption.  It seems like here it is because of the form of the energy $f(x).$

Comment: "Minimizing $f(x)$ and solving $Ax=b$ are equivalent" - as I know both have the same results, but different methodology is used to get the final value. I have specific task in which I need to use conjugate gradient as minimization of $f(x)=$$\frac{1}{2}$$ x^T*A*x-b^T*x$. My professor is very strict about this and he told me that α is calculated differently for quadratic functions and differently for linear. Therefore, my question is very simple: how to calculate α for quadratic functions.

Comment: Different methodology is not used to get the final value if you are still talking about CG.  Start with initial guess $x_0$. You take the negative gradient of $f,$ this is the residual $r_0 = b - Ax_0$ at $x_0.$  If its nonzero, the there exists an $\alpha$ such that $f(x_0 + \alpha r_0) < f(x_0).$  Setting $\alpha = r_0^Tr_0 / (r_0^T A r_0)$ minimizes $f(x_0 + \alpha r_0),$ then iterate until the residual is small.  Either your professor is incorrect, is asking a vastly different question, or you are not understanding the method and should refer to a textbook.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. In such situation I think I had to misunderstand my professor.